# It it posible to set up ssh config in such a way connections to host.alias get resolved to "host.subdomain"

Tags: linux, networking, openssh

I connect to a series of servers in the form of `host.subdomain.domain.example.com` different subdomains may or may not have hosts with the same name.

an obviously simple solution would be to do something like

```
host *
    hostname %h.domain.example.com
```

and simply do `ssh user@host.subdomain1`

However, subdomains are very similarly long and unreadable names prone to errors. What I currently do is to use a bash alias which calls to a function and resolves some user friendly names to the right subdomain from a lookup table and launches an ssh command of form `ssh user@host.subdomain1`

But I wonder if there is a way to do it directly from ssh's configuration

e.g.,

```
host *.alias1
hostname [host without .alias1].subdomain1.domain.example.com

host *.alias2
hostname [host without .alias2].subdomain2.domain.example.com

host *.alias3
hostname [host without .alias3].subdomain3.domain.example.com
```

==================================== EDIT ===============================

this sort of does what I want

```
host name-alias1
    User user
    hostname name.subdomain1

host name-alias2
    User user
    hostname name.subdomain2

match host *subdomain1 
     CanonicalizeHostname Yes
     CanonicalDomains      domain.example.com 
     [connection rules for subdomain1 ] 

match host *subdomain2 
     CanonicalizeHostname Yes
     CanonicalDomains      domain.example.com 
     [connection rules for subdomain2 ]
```